# Are multiple flags on the same question now allowed?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, flags

I thought one could only flag a post once, and that after that it should display:

[image]

But my flag summary shows that I've managed to flag a question twice (I didn't realise I had):

[image]

Has flagging recently been changed to allow more than one flag, is this a bug, or have I missed something?

Comment: You can flag for spam and something else, like on one post I had first flag as NAA and then, after stumbling on another post of the same user, I realized it was spam. So I came back on the post and flagged it as spam, and the 2 flags were active at the same moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reflag after the previous flag was handled, I assume that is what happened in your example.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense (of course). Thanks, I'll accept shortly.

Answer (score 0):

No, the rule is still the same. But in fact it happened when you flagged the post for second time; the first flagged was already handled by 10K+ users.