# Improved formatting after raising a flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

There was a [Question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/37466/21234) (now closed) asked on security.SE which I found to be low quality and unclear. It was not clear what the OP was asking and he had appended the secret key to the cipher-text (It's a sin!!!) so I flagged the question (very low quality).

After flagging I noticed that the title of the question was repeated in the question so I made an [edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/37466/revisions) and also added a tag. Of-course the edit was done only to improve the formatting of the question and there was no quality improvement. After this I noted that my flag was [disputed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag) because of the edit that I made.

I was wondering in case a flag is disputed, are the mods still able to see it? 
Is it right to mark a flag disputed after minor edits? I understand it is not possible for the application to judge the quality of a question.

I feel If the flag is disputed after an edit then one should also be allowed to re-flag the questions after an edit ( I was not allowed to reflag the question)

Update: According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176910/201081) once the flag is handled one may re-flag a question. But may be it does not happen in case of disputed ones or may be it was because I was the one who made the edit. Please share your views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Description of the **Low-quality Flag**:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question
>   is unlikely to be  salvageable through editing, and might need to be
>   removed.

Since you or someone edited the post to improve formatting then the system automatically nullifies the low-quality flag (by marking it as disputed). Reason being that the original premise of the flag becomes invalid. You flagged the post because you thought that the post has severe formatting problems but then a try was made to fix the formatting problem so after that there is no need for the mod to take a look at the flag.

> in case a flag is disputed, are the mods still able to see it?

I think, no. Flag was processed by the system so no need for any further action from a moderator.

> Is it right to mark a flag disputed after minor edits?

Is seems right in case of a Low-quality flag.

> I understand it is not possible for the application to judge the quality of a question

Yes, application is not judging the quality of a question. In this case, the system has only judged if the flag is still valid or not after an edit has been made.

Comment: Well in this case the post had severe content problems,like I mentioned.

Comment: @MayankSharma: if a post can't be salvaged via editing, don't edit it - if it's destined for the garbage can, don't waste your time on it. If it might be salvageable, don't flag VLQ.

Comment: If the flag is disputed after an edit then one should also be allowed to re-flag the questions after the edit.

Comment: @MayankSharma Based on the following post, you should be able to re-flag: [Are multiple flags on the same question now allowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176910/are-multiple-flags-on-the-same-question-now-allowed/176911)

Comment: Thanks for the link.I got the same message "You have already flagged this post". The link says after the flag has been handled you may re-flag the question.hmmm..not sure about the disputed ones.